# How to redirect to Different Page for User in Spartacus if he belongs to Different User group

Tags: spartacus-storefront, sap-commerce-cloud

When an employee logs in to CX if he has a salesManagerGroup I need to redirect to him a different page rather than a Home page.

How can I achieve this in Spartacus? Any  document  or steps would be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a guard to do this (please check how `AuthGuard` works).